# Trying to toggle a checkbox when another element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have p tag and when I click on the p tag I want to toggle the checkbox's check. right now it only works on the first toggle. when I click on the p the box gets checked and when I click on it again the box gets unchecked but that's it. If I click on it again nothing happens on the screen. when I inspect element in firebug the checked attribute appears and disappears, which I think is what is supposed to happen, but nothing appears on the screen. I tried using prop() and it didn't work. here's what I have with attr()

```
$(".clickMe").on("click", function(){
    if($("#thisBox").attr("checked") ){
        $("#thisBox").removeAttr("checked")
    }else{
        $("#thisBox").attr("checked","checked")
    }
})
```

And could someone tell me if there is a way to check to see if an element changes. Like `**if**($(el).changes(){ do this } )` what's the pattern for that

Comment: Please see below given answer with example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(".clickMe").on("click", function(){
    if($('#thisBox')[0].checked){
         $('#thisBox').prop('checked', false);
    }else{
        $('#thisBox').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="thisBox" /> Testing Checkbox

<input type="button" class="clickMe" text="test" value="testing button"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6d1rkd64/)

```
$(".clickMe").on("click", function(){
    if($("#thisBox").is(':checked')){
         $('#thisBox').prop('checked', false);
    }else{
         $('#thisBox').prop('checked', true);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just trigger the event:

```
$(".clickMe").on("click", function(){
    $("#thisBox").trigger("click");
});
```

[LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/ot3j60nr/)

Comment: This should be the cleanest answer. Only thing is that if you need to perform any activities on checking the box, you need to define the checkbox click function manually

Comment: @ArinCool ...You can personalize too... Look at this: _http://jsfiddle.net/ot3j60nr/2/_